# What is the name of the artist on this piece?

Tags: character-identification

Could someone type the name of the artist in Chinese so I can begin research on this piece? I purchased a translation application that works well but it will not pick up words that have been written by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"馬海德", most likely was "shafick george Hatem" and his wife "周蘇菲".

于延安 is roughly at (于) the communist headquarters (延安)

Answer (score 4):

```
壽比南山不老松

一九四四年聖誕佳節
    持贈
美國軍事參觀團   存念
        蘇  菲
             于延安
        馬海德
```

[image]

Image source: [Yan'an (China), Ma Haide (George Hatem) and his wife, Chou Sufei, 1944](https://collections.lib.uwm.edu/digital/collection/agsphoto/id/11395)